# C# array question (split)

Tags: c#, arrays, memory, copy

Question very simple - say, i got function, which receives array as its arguments

```
void calc(double[] data)
```

how do "split" this data in two subarrays and pass to sub functions like this

```
calc_sub(data(0, length/2));
cals_sub(data(length /2, length /2));
```

i hope, you got the idea - in c++ i would write this

```
void calc(double * data, int len)
{
   calc_sub(data, len / 2); //this one modifies data!!
   calc_sub(data + len / 2, len / 2); //this one modifies data too!!
}
```

How to do same in C# without unecesary memory copying?
I would need 2 memory copies here. 
1) from data to splitted data
2) calc_sub
3) from splitted data back to data! This is huge waste of time and memory!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what calc_sub does, you can make a IEnumerable class which takes the array and iterates over some part of the array. Something like [ArraySegment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d%28VS.80%29.aspx), but [better](http://weblogs.asp.net/wim/archive/2006/06/14/ArraySegment-Structure---what-were-they-thinking_3F00_.aspx).

Answer (score 8):

The easiest is probably using LINQs [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) and [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) extension methods:

```
int half = data.Length / 2;
double[] sub1 = data.Take(half).ToArray();
double[] sub2 = data.Skip(half).ToArray();
```

Comment: Easy to read solution but I'm pretty sure it's rather slow since both tak,skip and ToArray probably results in a simple iteration of the collection resulting in two full iterations of the original data. If the size of the original data is low or time is not an issue it's a nice readable solution

Comment: Is it fast? CLR knows, how to optimize this stuff?

Comment: I always try to write readable code and later perform load testing to verify if performance wasn't hurt. If this is the case then refactor.

Comment: To clarify about the performance: `Take` and `Skip` create a new enumerator from the original collection. So until you call `ToArray` nothing happens. Once you call `ToArray` half of the original array is iterated in order to create a new array, so both operations basically cost you a full iteration over the original array plus the memory it takes to store the new sub-arrays.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is that to get a subarray, you'd have to create a new array and copy elements...  Or if you were using c++, you'd be memcpying.

Now, why not just take the offset/count approach?
When calling `calc_sub(blargh[] array)`, instead use `calc_sub(blargh[] array, int offset, int count)`?

This is basically the c# way of passing a pointer to the start/half-pos element and telling the function to work on only half the array's elements.

---

I should note that unless you're working with huge double arrays, you really shouldn't be worrying about this.  64 bits = 8 bytes.  Even if you had an array of 1000 elements, that's 8000 bytes, ~8 kB of memory, which you will pretty much free in less than a second...

Now, it's always a good idea to conserve memory where possible, but I'd rule this as premature optimization.

I should also note that arrays are passed by reference, as they are really objects, as opposed to ints or strings, so this method is the best memory-wise [it doesn't copy the array; it gives something like a pointer to the array object], but it's limited in that modifying the array in your function will modify the array passed outside of your function call.

Comment: tons of code using "that" approach. Copy works allways, but aint there any "smarter" solution?

Answer (score 1):

Go ahead and write your own subarray function like this:

```
public static class ArrayExtensions
{
  T[] SubArray<T>(this T[] arr, int startIndex,int count)
  {
    var sub = new T[count];
    Array.Copy(arr,startIndex,sub,o,count);
    return sub;
  }
}
```

and then you can use it like:

```
void calc(double[] data)
{
  var half = data.Length /2;
  data.SubArray(0, half ));
  data.SubArray(half , half ));
}
```

Comment: Already in my `public static class Extentions`...  A must have in my opinion.

Comment: @0xDEAD BEEF, But calc sub returns a value calculated by the passed array, right?  We honestly don't know what calc_sub does, so it's not really possible for us to give advice 100% targeted to you; we're guessing on what your situation is.

Comment: @0xDEAD BEEF and what's the issue with splitting the array and then iterating to do the calculation? or would you preferre to do have a transformation operation instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you can make the `calc_sub` method take an `IEnumerable<double>` instead of a `double[]`, you can use extension methods to create expressions that return part of the array:

```
void calc(double[] data) {
  int half = data.Length / 2;
  calc_sub(data.Take((half));
  calc_sub(data.Skip(half));
}
```

This way you don't have to copy the data to new arrays, the expressions will return items from the original array.

Comment: Is it fast? Calling IEnumberable.value instead of direct array access??

Comment: it's reasonably fast but not as fast as direct access but do you know you have a performance problem?